# Change default registry for docker push commands

Tags: docker, docker-registry

There is an option to set `registry-mirrors` in `daemon.json` of docker to config default registry while pulling images.

Is there another way so I can push docker images to a local registry by default (without specifying local registry URL)?

To describe more, we have 2 nexus repositories, one as proxy of default registry (so we pull images through it), and one hosted one.

We want all developers push their images to our hosted registry, not docker hub.

Answer (score 0):

`registry-mirrors` is a mirror of Docker Hub, so the design is to push to the authoritative source, and if a pull to one of the Hub mirrors fails, that will also fall back to Hub.

It looks like what you are trying to do is merge a multiple namespaces into one, the namespace for Hub, and the namespace for your local Nexus repositories. Doing that is dangerous because deploying the same image reference on different machines, or when the Nexus instance is unavailable for any reason, will result in a dependency confusion attack.

The design of image references is to always specify the registry when you don't want to use Docker Hub. This avoids the dependency confusion attacks seen by other package repositories.

If you're worried about developers pushing images to Hub that they shouldn't be, then I'd recommend setting up an HTTP proxy that rejects POST and PUT requests to `registry-1.docker.io` (a pull uses GET and HEAD requests), and make sure all developers use that proxy (typically via a network policy that doesn't allow direct access without the proxy).